# How to self-join a table with more than 100k+ rows per key?

Tags: apache-spark, fuzzy-search, sparklyr, cross-join

I am trying to find similar company names using spark and R. Currently my dataset has over 500 million rows and this will only increase in the future. The count of unique company names is 75M+. I'm running this on AWS EMR with 15 nodes and a master node. The spark settings are as follows:

spark.executor.cores: 3

spark.executor.memory: 30g

spark.driver.memory: 80g

spark.driver.cores: 8

spark.memory.fraction: 0.1

spark.executor.memoryOverhead: 5g

Number of nodes: 15 (64 cores, 488 GB ram and 200GB SSD each) number of executors per node: 13 partition multiplier: 19

To do this, I'm first finding out the SOUNDEX of each company name and then doing a self join in SOUNDEX and first two alphabets of each company. After the join, I would want to find out the Levenshtein distance between the two company names (in each row) and choose the most popular one if the distance is within limits, else, ignore that row.

The problem lies in self-join (as far as I know, but I'd be happy to accept other recommendations or alternative approach to the problem)

I've tried increasing the partitions multiplier to 100 or decreasing the spark.executor.cores to 2.

I've also tried to join the table on SOUNDEX and first three alphabets.

**Code:**

**spark + R**

```
    dist.frac=0.2
    min.dist.float = 0.7
    max.dist.float=4
    method='dl'
    old.col='company_name'
    pref = 'fuzzy'
    substr.mn = 1
    substr.mx = 2
    weight=c(1,1,1,1)

    new.col = paste(pref, old.col, sep='_')

    spark_df =
        spark_df %>%
        rename(old_col = old.col)

    fuzzy_spark_df =
        spark_df %>%
        group_by(old_col) %>%
        summarize(freq = count()) %>%
        mutate(character_count = length(old_col)) %>%
        mutate(max_dist = pmin(pmax(min.dist.float, dist.frac*character_count), max.dist.float)) %>%
        mutate(grpcol = paste(soundex(old_col), '|', substr(old_col, substr.mn, substr.mx))) %>%
        filter(character_count >= 2)

    fuzzy_spark_df =
        fuzzy_spark_df %>%
        sdf_persist(persist.type)

    fuzzy_spark_df =
        fuzzy_spark_df %>%
        sdf_repartition(partition_by = c('grpcol'), partitions = n.partitions)

    collect(head(fuzzy_spark_df)) # to force compuations

    logNote('performing the cross join')

    fuzzy_spark_df =
        fuzzy_spark_df %>% select(old_col, grpcol) %>%
        inner_join(fuzzy_spark_df, by=c('grpcol'), suffix=c('_orig', '_fuzzy'))

    fuzzy_spark_df =
        fuzzy_spark_df %>%
        mutate(distance = levenshtein(old_col_orig, old_col_fuzzy))

    fuzzy_spark_df =
        fuzzy_spark_df %>%
        filter(max_dist >= distance) %>%
        group_by(old_col_orig) %>%
        filter(freq == max(freq, na.rm = T) & distance == min(distance, na.rm = T)) %>%
        arrange(old_col_fuzzy) %>%
        filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
        select('old_col_orig', 'old_col_fuzzy') %>%
        distinct()

    spark_df =
        spark_df %>%
        sdf_broadcast() %>%
        left_join(fuzzy_spark_df, by = c('old_col' = 'old_col_orig')) %>%
        mutate(old_coenter code herel_fuzzy = ifelse(is.na(old_col_fuzzy) | is.null(old_col_fuzzy), 'blank', old_col_fuzzy)) %>%
        rename(!!old.col := 'old_col', !!new.col := 'old_col_fuzzy')
```

spark data frame spark_df:

```
  company_name join_col
  walgreens     W123 | wa
  walgreen      W123 | wa
  walmart       W123 | wa
  cisco         C654 | ci
  cicso         C654 | ci
  carta         C986 | ca
```

Output (inner join spark_df on col join_col)

```
   company_name    join_col    fuzzy_company_name
     walgreens     W123 | wa   walgreen
     walgreens     W123 | wa   walgreens
     walgreens     W123 | wa   walmart
     walgreen      W123 | wa   walgreen
     walgreen      W123 | wa   walgreens
     walgreen      W123 | wa   walmart
     walmart       W123 | wa   walgreen
     walmart       W123 | wa   walgreens
     walmart       W123 | wa   walmart
     cisco         C654 | ci   cisco
     cisco         C654 | ci   cicso
     cicso         C654 | ci   cicso
     cicso         C654 | ci   cisco
     carta         C986 | ca   carta
```

Comment: Why so much allocated to driver?

Comment: Because my worker wasn't doing anything else. Can a big driver cause problem?

Comment: Driver normally get little resources, the workers do the work.

Comment: I can decrease the size of master node.

Comment: Afaik EMR master node is not same as driver node.

Comment: So, the driver should be at least the size of executor, right?

Comment: most work should be done by executors, surely?

Comment: yes. I just read somewhere that driver should be at least as big as any executor. Also, I used to think that the master node on EMR is used as a driver. Also upon checking the SparkUI while a job is running, it uses all the cores assigned to any executor, so I just thought the driver is running on Master.

Comment: Not so. You read things stating mcdonalds is top cuisine, not so.

Comment: I am on hols, I will think when I get back next week.

Comment: yeah sure. whatever time works for you.